# Fetch unsupported_grant_type in React Native v0.63.2

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, access-token

I'm Request Token in Postman successfully but in React Native Project:

> {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

My code I'm copy from PostMan:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("username", "hoanglongit96");
    urlencoded.append("password", "admin");
    urlencoded.append("grant_type", "password");

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: urlencoded,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://192.168.1.38:7777/token", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Result:

> {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

and I tried add **Accept: application/json** in header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I solved my problem! Hope can help everyone

```
body:urlencoded.toString()
```

Comment: Been searching for a solution to this problem for hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it with the following:

1. Change URL **HTTP** to **HTTPS**
2. Create file `network_security_config.xml` in `android/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <network-security-config>
          <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.135</domain>
      </domain-config>
   </network-security-config>
   ```